# How to describe a trail well for others in a systematic way?

Tags: trails, terminology

I occasionally design or lead hikes in areas with multiple trail junctions.  I attempt to be thorough in the planning by having several different ways for hikers to follow the trail. (Maps and GPS are the two main methods)

I am seeking a better way to verbally describe the planned hike route by describing the trails and turns in a systematic way.  I'd rather not devise my own nomenclature, as I have read very good trail descriptions in the past.  I am sure there is some well proven way of writing useful description using somewhat standardised language.

Can anyone point me to a good reference for this?

Comment: Terminology is likely to be specific to the location. Worse, the same words in different o location will have subtly (an not so subtly) different meanings. For instance, where I life we gave 'Great Walks' -  every year or two a people die on these multi day 'walks'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a minimum a trail description should include,

- Start
- End
- Distance/Elevation Change
- Estimated Time

For describing the actual trail you would want to include,

- The general direction.
- What the elevation trend is, uphill vs downhill or mixed.
- The type of terrain, rolling, forested, flat, lots of switch backs.
- Where water is along the trail and if applicable how long between water sources.
- Good places to camp along the trail (if backpacking.)
- Any places where a person could easily get lost or confused.
- Landmarks along the way.
- Directions for which junctions or turns to take.

Beyond that, there is a list of trail terms that can be found [here](http://www.americantrails.org/resources/info/TrailTermCOTI.html), and another [here.](https://adventures.hartleybrody.com/glossary-of-hiking-backpacking-terms-acronyms/#dirtbag)

Do be aware that trail terms depend on the culture and so can vary wildly.

Comment: >"Do be aware that trail terms depend on the culture and so can vary wildly."


My hiking group varies from 1/3 to 1/2 non-native English speakers.  Many new to outdoors activity.  This is one of the reasons I am looking for more standardised terms.  The link to American Trails has a number of terms to help avoid regionalisms and acronyms.  Jargon is not always avoidable when writing technical descriptions so more standardized terminology will help in communicating to my audience.